# How can I achieve this layout in Flutter? I tried using stack and OverflowBox, but still it doesn't look same as this

Tags: flutter, user-interface, layout, widget, frontend

[image]

It's basically a circular container behind a container with rounded edges. How can I do this in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 0, 10),
              child: Container(
                width: 200,
                height: 40,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              top: 0,
              child: Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 2
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```